# What is difference between 4 ways convert timezone in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I don't know What is difference between 4 ways convert timezone in postgresql:

```
SELECT (timestamp '2018-01-20 00:00:00' at time zone 'Asia/Saigon') at time zone 'UTC';


SELECT CAST('2018-01-20 00:00:00' as timestamp without time zone) at time zone 'Asia/Saigon' at time zone 'UTC'


SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-20 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'Asia/Saigon') at time zone 'UTC'


SELECT ('2018-01-20 00:00:00' at time zone 'Asia/Saigon') at time zone 'UTC';
```

The results are different. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two statements do the same thing.

The difference is the way in which a constant of type `timestamp without time zone` is created, but the result is the same in both cases.

The third statement creates a `timestamp with time zone` using `to_timestamp`, where the string is interpreted in your session time zone. This is then converted to a `timestamp without time zone` as the wall clock in Saigon would show, and then converted to a `timestamp with time zone` imagining the wall clock were teleported to UTC.

The fourth statement does the same as the third, because the string is implicitly cast to `timestamp with time zone`. There is an ambiguity here because `AT TIME ZONE` can also be applied to `timestamp without time zone`, but in case of doubt the *preferred type* of its category is used, which is `timestamp with time zone`.

Answer (score 1):

> The SQL standard differentiates timestamp without time zone and timestamp with time zone literals by the presence of a "+" or "-" symbol and time zone offset after the time. Hence, according to the standard

Also you can see below articles:

1. [Section 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.19.7)
2. [Time zone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)